# PS1 as ghost text?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, zsh

How exactly would I go from taking the value of $PS1 and putting the delimiter first with the text in the background? I received a suggestion to output the text to the terminal and then send len(expanded_PS1) non destructive backspaces. (preferably it would also clear once text is entered, and maybe even showing if the prompt is cleared)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (mis-)use `RPROMPT` instead of `PROMPT` (aka `PS1`) to achieve this, or at least something similar

`RPROMPT` is displayed right aligned on the same line as the prompt. If your typed command is long enough to reach it, `RPROMPT` will automatically be hidden (and also re-appear, if you delete enough).

So you could set `PROMPT` to only contain the prompt character and put everything else into `RPROMPT`. Then you pad `RPROMPT` with spaces until it fills the rest of the line, so that it nearly touches `PROMPT`. For example

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%# '
RPROMPT='%$((COLUMNS-4))>> %n@%m %~${(r:$COLUMNS:)}'
```

This should show something like

```
% ▒ user@machine ~
```

where `▒` is the position of the cursor. Once you start typing everything after it will be hidden. For example

```
% echo foo▒
```

#### Explanation:

- `setopt PROMPT_SUBST` enables the substitution of parameters in the prompt each time the prompt is displayed.
- `RPROMPT` needs to be defined in single quotes so that the parameters therein are not expanded immediately on definition but only once the prompt is displayed (with `PROMPT_SUBST` enabled). This ensures that the padding is working correctly even when the terminal window is resized.
- `%#` is the prompt character: `#` for root `%` for everybody else.
- `$COLUMNS` is the current width of the terminal.
- `%n>>` truncates everything to the right of it to `n` characters, cutting on the right side.
- `$((COLUMNS-4))` calculates the remaining width after the left prompt (`PROMPT`). In addition to the two characters in `PROMPT` you need to subtract one for the cursor and another one because `RPROMPT` does not cover the very last column on a line. (If you want to use a `PROMPT` of variable length, then you will have to calculate its length dynamically.)
- `%n@%m %~` is just an example and shows the username (`%n`), machine name (`%m`) and current directory (`%~`).
- `${(r:$COLUMNS:)}` is expanded to a string of spaces the same width as the terminal. This ensures that there are always enough padding spaces.

Comment: Hmm... I can't quite seem to get variations on your suggestions to work quite right, either in .zshrc.pre or .zshrc.local.

Comment: Not quite right how? Do you use something like *Oh-My-Zsh*? I am asking because neither `.zshrc.pre` nor `.zshrc.local` are regular configuration files for `zsh`. If so, it might be that it is somehow interfering. Does it work (or work differently) if you just run the three lines directly on the command line of a running `zsh` session?

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot, I wasn't able to add it as a tag, but yes, Grml-zsh-config is what I use across all of my systems (it's the default for Arch's install and I've grown comfortable with it)

Comment: So, I tried it with the grml zsh config and found that its prompt is quite resilient to change. This seems to be due to the use of the *zsh's Prompt Theme* system. You should be able to disable it by running `prompt restore` before changing any prompt variables. Of course you could also try to create your own theme utilizing my suggestions.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I'll have to settle for vertically splitting terminals in tmux rather than pseudo-ghost-text, given how much I imagine that would disable.

Comment: To clarify, grml is the default shell setup for the Arch Linux install**er**. It does not come with the *zsh* package on Arch by default.